# Access enum between scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I am trying access a public enum from a script to another but I can't get it to work. If I understand correctly, if you have a script outside the class like this:

```
public class Regions : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {     
    }

    void Update () {        
    }
}

public enum BiomeList
{
    BiomeList
}
```

You should be able to use it in all other scripts, but I can't access it.
If I copy the public enum code and put it in another script at the bottom, I can access it from the script that I want to with this code.

```
public BiomeList biomeFound;
```

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you saved your `Regions` script? Maybe you didn't save it yet so it's not available else where. Ctrl+S to save.

Comment: @Programmer Yes I have saved and restarted unity several times.

Comment: This was fixed with a computer restart; this question has no value to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the computer fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your IDE has trouble locating the enum.

Try put it inside a namespace and see if that allows you to access it.

Normally as Foggzie points out, if it's inside a class you can access it as he describes it.

A namespace should provide similar accessibility if you don't want it inside a class.

Could make a namespace called "GlobalEnums" or similar and import it from there.